# Динамическое использование библиотек, разработанных для ВС++, в Delfi

Tags: c++builder, delphi, библиотеки, dll

Динамическое использование библиотек, разработанных для ВС++, в Delfi

Comment: Уточните, в чем заключается Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
 myFunc : function(a1:PAnsiChar;a2:PAnsiChar):Bool; stdcall;
```

так должно заработать.

Answer (score 1):

Динамическая подгрузка DLL:

```
 var
     handle: THandle;
     calc: procedure (x: Integer); {$IFDEF WIN32} stdcall; {$ENDIF}
 begin
     handle := LoadLibrary('library.dll');
     if handle >= 32 then
     begin
         calc := GetProcAddress(handle, 'calc');
         calc(0);
         FreeLibrary(handle);
     end
 end
```